# How to properly routing for SPA using Angular 1.5?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application, ngroute

I'm new to angular. I create a blog for showing my profile. 
In my website, I have several component and my app.module has a configuration for the routing, as shown:

```
app.config(function($locationProvider, $routeProvider){
  $locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled:true,
    requireBase: false
  })

  $routeProvider.
    when("/", {
      template: "<research-overview></research-overview>"
    }).
    when("/research-interests", {
      template: "<research-interests></research-interests>"
    }).
    otherwise({
      redirectTo: "/"
    })
 });
```

Here is an example of my component:

```
angular.module('researchOverview', [])
  .component('researchOverview', {
     templateUrl: '/templates/research-overview.html',
});
```

I tried to locally run the server using `python -m SimpleHttpServer`
so that I can access my local website using browser to `localhost:8000`, When I click a link from my homepage, the page is correctly loaded. However, when I initially access my website using different urls (e.g. `localhost:8000/testing`) Angular route doesn't seem to work properly.
I get this error instead,

[image]

How do I set the router so that those urls can be redirected to my homepage?

Comment: you can't use `html5Mode` with Python SimpleHttpServer without writing your own subclass for it, eg. https://gist.github.com/RyanBalfanz/ee579e5dec2d843acff1646943d7e96b

Comment: ah!! the problem is with the simpleHttpServer? Thanks for this

Comment: you should use "real" urls if you want to show such urls, so that users can bookmark and resume tabs; that means you need actual pages at every location you give out a url to. it can be a common error page, or you can work with a server to server the actual eventual content, boosting SEO.

Answer (score 0):

Given you have enabled html5 mode I think you may need to set your server up so that regardless of the path it will return your index.html file.

For example, when your server receives a request for a resource at localhost:8000/testing it will return index.html.

From the AngularJS documentation:

> Using this mode requires URL rewriting on server side, basically you
>   have to rewrite all your links to entry point of your application
>   (e.g. index.html). Requiring a  tag is also important for this
>   case, as it allows Angular to differentiate between the part of the
>   url that is the application base and the path that should be handled
>   by the application.

Comment: how do I did that?

Comment: I have just updated my answer with some more information. I haven't used python myself so I can't provide specifics unfortunately.